# swift parsing desc and parsing selected element

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

Swift parsing desc and parsing selected element. I want to parse desc and after parsing desc parse desc content. thanks swift parsing desc and parsing selected element.

I have tried different methods. Does anyone have an idea on how we can make it possible? I tried the following code:

```
**Code for getting the data**

 func demoApi1() {
        Alamofire.request("", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Ang Response: , \(json)")

                for item in json {

                  self.getAllDetail.append(item )


                    if let desc = item["dec"] as? String {
                        self.titleArray.append(desc)

                        print("motherfucker:" , self.titleArray)

                    }

                }
                if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }
```

**Response:**

```
 Ang Response [["status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "sched": 2018-04-10T14:22:00+08:00, "desc": asdasdasdsa, "id": 224, "reward": 1.00, "parent": das, "child": dasdas, "date_created": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00, "name": sad, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": , "date_modified": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.703520+08:00], ["status": {
    name = ongoing;
}, "sched": 2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00, "desc": {
  "questions" : [
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 1
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 2
    },
    {
      "b" : 2,
      "a" : 8
    },
    {
      "b" : 9,
      "a" : 7
    },
    {
      "b" : 3,
      "a" : 6
    }
  ],
  "operation" : "addition"
}, "id": 226, "reward": 1.00, "parent": shit, "child": , "date_created": 2018-04-23T14:16:35.739436+08:00, "name": chorename, "occurrence": {
    name = once;
}, "type": homework, "date_modified": 2018-04-23T14:16:35.790237+08:00]]
```

Comment: Can you share the raw format of the response of api, this seems to be incorrect

Comment: The value for key `desc` is a JSON string which needs to be deserialized with `JSONSerialization` and this response is edited so it's pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String to Dictionary:

```
   func stringToDictionary(_ strToJSON : String)-> [String:Any]{

    print("JsonString:\(strToJSON)")

    let data = strToJSON.data(using: .utf8)
    var dict = [String:Any]()
    do {
        dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any] 
        return dict
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error is:\(error)")
    }

    return dict
}
```

**Use it like this:**

```
let dictConv = stringToDictionary("your_string")
print(dictConv)
```

Comment: @DurnKurvirck Can you share the print(dictConv) so that i can further decode that

Comment: Please folks stop suggesting `.mutableContainers` in Swift. This option has no effect at all. Remove the `options` parameter.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the suggestion, will keep that in mind in future

Comment: `.allowFragments` is also pointless if the expected type is a collection type. Once again: *Remove the parameter* -> No options.

Comment: edited the answer @vadian, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore can you please comment your email here your facebook or gmail. Thanks

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck my email id is abhirajsinhthakore007@gmail.com, same for FB

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore ill be sending you an email

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck yes will be looking for that surely.

Comment: Have you seen the mail i have send on you